# Getting 'TypeError: null is not an object' with prompt in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a little issue here, and I cannot find what exactly is wrong. I would like to use prompt in my react-native app. But when I do so, then I get this error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'PromptAndroid.promptWithArgs')
```

Let me show you some of my code.
At very start I have imported prompt like this:

```
import prompt from 'react-native-prompt-android';
```

Then I have this function which using prompt itself:

```
    _handleAddProductPress() {
    prompt (
        'Enter product name',
        '',
        [
            { text: 'Cancel', style: 'cancel'},
            { text: 'OK', onPress: this.addNewProduct.bind(this)}
        ],
        {
            type: 'plain-text'
        }
    );
}
```

And finally, this function is called within my render function like this:

```
            <Fab
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF'}}
                position="bottomRight"
                onPress={this._handleAddProductPress.bind(this)}
                >
                <Icon name="add" />
            </Fab>
```

I installed prompt like it says in documentation `npm i react-native-prompt-android --save`.
Really don't know why am I getting this error? I really can't see the reason. If anyone have idea or any lead how to solve this unhappy problem, I will be grateful.

Thanks a lot for any advice.
AV.

P.S.: I am using Expo as well but I don't think that would be a case.

Comment: Did you run the **react-native link react-native-prompt-android** command for linking ?

Comment: I did autolinking. Now I tried your link command just to be sure. It returns some warning that it's deprecated and I should use autolink.

Comment: Also I did autolink once again right now, but no outcome :(

Answer (score 0):

A native code won't link correctly

To test:

```js
import { NativeModules} from 'react-native';

console.log( { PromptAndroid: NativeModules.PromptAndroid } ) //  { PromptAndroid: null }
```

Please sure that you rebuild an Android app after installing `react-native-prompt-android`

Also, you can remove a Gradle cache, then rebuilt the app again

```sh
# to clear cache
rm -rf android/app/build
npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am gonna try that test. You telling me to rebuild app, how exactly do you mean this? I am using expo and app is not in apk yet. Only thing that I can do is shut down expo server, save files (to be sure) and start expo server once again.

Comment: And yes... In that console.log I can see PromptAndroid: null

Comment: seem you need to make eject, https://docs.expo.io//expokit/eject